# Rstudio Server vs El Capitan

Tags: homebrew, r

I am trying to install RStudio Server in OSX El Capitan.

I did these steps from terminal

```
brew install openssl

brew install homebrew/science/rstudio-server
```

I have the login window at localhost:8787 but I can't login. If I run

```
sudo rstudio-server status
```

then I get

```
Could not find service "com.rstudio.launchd.rserver" in domain for
```

To check the installation I run

```
sudo rstudio-server verify-installation
```

and I get

```
21 Oct 2016 05:11:44 [rserver] ERROR system error 48 (Address already in use); 
OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(SocketAcceptorService<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &, const std::string &, const std::string &) /tmp/rstudio-server-20161017-46697-nr3wo3/rstudio-
0.99.902/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/TcpIpSocketUtils.hpp:103; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char *const *) /tmp/rstudio-server-20161017-46697-nr3wo3/rstudio-0.99.902/src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:438
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: As 2018-03-05, the formula of rstudio-server has moved to https://github.com/randy3k/homebrew-r as homebrew-science is deprecated

Comment: The formula of rstudio-server is now housed in https://github.com/brewsci/homebrew-base

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to install and launch the related launch daemon and modify some other things. To fix this do the following:

- Copy a pre-made plist:

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/local/opt/rstudio-server/share/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
  ```
- Check permissions:

  ```
  sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist 
  sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
  ```
- Modify the plist:

  ```
  sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
  ```

  and replace

  ```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/rstudio-server/bin/rserver</string>
      <string>--server-daemonize=0</string>
  </array>
  ```

  by

  ```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/rstudio-server/bin/rserver</string>
      <string>--server-daemonize=0</string>
      <string>--auth-minimum-user-id=500</string>
  </array>
  ```

  This step is necessary because rstudio-server's default auth-minimum-user-id is 1000 and the common OS X user's first ID is 501, the second user's ID is 502 etc.
- Copy a pam:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/pam.d/ftpd /etc/pam.d/rstudio
  ```
- Launch the daemon and start rstudio:

  ```
  sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
  sudo rstudio-server start
  ```

Finally launch a broswer, enter *localhost:8787* in the address bar and log-in with your OS X user credentials.

To stop rstudio server enter `sudo rstudio-server stop`. After a reboot you have to enter `sudo rstudio-server start` to start it again.

---

If you want the rstudio-server to be launched automatically while booting, stop the server, unload the launch daemon,

```
sudo rstudio-server stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
```

modify the file /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist with *nano* and set the RunAtLoad key from *false* to *true*. Finally load the launch daemon again:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this clearly helps
I had to do an additional step that is to go to apple icon -> system preferences -> users & groups and add the group rstudio
then it works

Comment: probably network settings or something... but it works great !

Comment: @pachamaltese I don't have to create an rstudio group to have access immediately - but maybe I'm missing something because I set up a vanilla brew install of r/rstudio. But the [description on your web page](http://pacha.hk/rstudio_server.html) is not correct: if you set the key [RunAtLoad] to true, you **don't** have to start rstudio server explicitly once more with `sudo rstudio-server start` because it already runs after booting OS X.

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: yes, that's right
I did set autoboot not to run `sudo rstudio-server start`

Comment: I wrote that to have a safe copy if I break something later. The second after I install rstudio-server via brew I need to run `sudo rstudio-server start`

Comment: I am the one who wrote the homebrew formula for rstudio-server. Glad to know that someone is actually using that formula. (I discovered this thread just by chance)

Answer (score 1):

I Just want to give some updates for the updated formula `rstudio-server v1.0.153`.

Some of the files have been relocated for consistency.

```
/usr/local/opt/rstudio-server/share/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
```

was moved to

```
/usr/local/opt/rstudio-server/extras/launchd/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist
```

and the pam file is now bundled with the formula

```
/usr/local/opt/rstudio-server/extras/pam/rstudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have explained the steps you provided and more: http://pacha.hk/rstudio_server.html

In general, you just can't restart the server without affecting other users.

Thanks a lot for the instructions.