# Rstudio Server in Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave, osx-server, r

I am trying to install Rstudio Server in Mac mini running on macOS Mojave. I followed [this link](https://iangow.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/rstudio-server-on-mac-os-x/) to build Rstudio server from the source. I also looked at [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258105/rstudio-server-vs-el-capitan/258147#258147). I could successfully install it with no problems. 
But I get this error:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/rstudio-server/bin
$ rserver --server-daemonize=0  --auth-minimum-user-id=500 
rserver: command not found
```

I have the .plist and everything in the right place (needed to run rstudio server in the backend) but I don't get why does it say rserver command not found? I can provide any other detail if needed.

Comment: 1. rserver is not in the PATH 2. check with `ls` (or another tool) if *rserver* is in */usr/local/lib/rstudio-server/bin/*. 3. If true use `./rserver --server-daemonize=0  --auth-minimum-user-id=500`! 4. Else: check whether rserver is somewhere else (e.g. /usr/local/opt/....

Comment: @klanomath thanks! rserver is in my path in that directory. Okay, so I see that it has to be executed. It wasn't clear from the documents I was reading like https://github.com/randy3k/homebrew-r/issues/34 where it was talking about how to test the server. But, I am now getting a new error  "[rserver] ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [description: Failed to get user details., user-value: ]". Not related to this question, I understand. Any clue? -- thanks again.

Comment: (With 1. [...] PATH I meant the system variable but not *the path in that directory* ;-)) Prepend `sudo `?

Comment: I used sudo command as well but got the same error.

Comment: I tried to install r/rserver and all dependencies with brew (I had to add some tap because the official brew doesn't provide rserver) but finally failed to launch it properly (some ssh lib problem). It will take some time to set up a VM and get this to work with *MacPort*. Did you execute the `sudo cp /etc/pam.d/ftpd /etc/pam.d/rstudio` step? Other sources use another pam.d/ file - I don't remember which one though.

Comment: @klanomath, Sorry for taking so long in answering here. I was able to solve these problems and get Rstudio-server up and running using built-in Apache. The problem was mainly in file permissions and ownership. Rstudio Server was not able to write in /var/run along with a few other similar problems. I had to create a subdirectory .Rstudio in my home directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

When any Unix/MacOS/BSD resides on the current directory **and** this directory is not in your environment variable **PATH**, you **must** prefix it with `./` to have it executed.

According to you, the binary IS on the current direcoty, so the command line has to be:

```
./rserver --server-daemonize=0  --auth-minimum-user-id=500
```